# UIPickerView delegate is called infinite number of times

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uipickerview

I have a very old app where I have UIPickerView where delegate method is called n number of times & because of which application is crashing.

Below is what I have.

1. I have already connection UIPickerView to its delegates.
2. I have label and on tapping on it, I am showing gender in uipickerview.

   ```
   langLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
   UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizergenderLabel = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(genderLabelTapped)];
   tapGestureRecognizergenderLabel.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
   [langLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizergenderLabel];
   [tapGestureRecognizergenderLabel release];

   -(void) genderLabelTapped {
       NSLog(@"genderLabelTapped");
       [normalPicker reloadAllComponents];
       normalPicker.hidden = NO;
       pickerImage.hidden = NO;
       continueButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
   }
   ```
3. I have delegates as below.

   ```
   #pragma mark -
   #pragma mark PickerView DataSource

   - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
   {
       NSLog(@"numberOfComponentsInPickerView");
       return 1;
   }

   -(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
   {
       CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
       CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

       if (screenHeight==568) {
           [pickerView setFrame: CGRectMake(10, 332, 300, 216)];
       } else {
           [pickerView setFrame: CGRectMake(10, 244, 300, 216)];
       }
       UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 204, 44)]; // your frame, so picker gets "colored"

       label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
       label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", localize(@"myFontNameB")] size:14];
       label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

       label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrayGender objectAtIndex:row]];
       NSLog(@"changing font 1111...===%@", [arrayGender objectAtIndex:row]);
       return label;
   }

   - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
   {
       return [arrayGender count];
   }

   - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
   {
       return [arrayGender objectAtIndex:row];
   }
   ```
4. Gender array I have is as below.

   ```
   arrayGender = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   [arrayGender addObject:@"ENGLISH"];
   [arrayGender addObject:@"العربية"];
   ```

Whenever I run this code, I always see below output...

```
    Oct 24 12:36:25 HardTask-iPad AppName[543] <Warning>: changing font 1111...===ENGLISH
    Oct 24 12:36:25 HardTask-iPad AppName[543] <Warning>: changing font 1111...===العربية
    Oct 24 12:36:25 HardTask-iPad AppName[543] <Warning>: changing font 1111...===ENGLISH
    Oct 24 12:36:25 HardTask-iPad AppName[543] <Warning>: changing font 1111...===العربية
    Oct 24 12:36:25 HardTask-iPad AppName[543] <Warning>: changing font 1111...===ENGLISH
    Oct 24 12:36:25 HardTask-iPad AppName[543] <Warning>: changing font 1111...===العربية
    Oct 24 12:36:25 HardTask-iPad AppName[543] <Warning>: changing font 1111...===ENGLISH
    Oct 24 12:36:25 HardTask-iPad AppName[543] <Warning>: changing font 1111...===العربية
    .
    .
    .
    Oct 24 12:36:26 HardTask-iPad AppName[543] <Warning>: changing font 1111...===ENGLISH
    Oct 24 12:36:26 HardTask-iPad AppName[543] <Warning>: changing font 1111...===العربية
    Oct 24 12:36:26 HardTask-iPad AppName[543] <Warning>: changing font 1111...===ENGLISH
    Oct 24 12:36:26 HardTask-iPad AppName[543] <Warning>: changing font 1111...===العربية
```

***Any idea what is going wrong?***

Comment: Try to remove `if (screenHeight==568) {
        [pickerView setFrame: CGRectMake(10, 332, 300, 216)];
    } else {
        [pickerView setFrame: CGRectMake(10, 244, 300, 216)];
    }` and what happen?

Comment: @anhtu : hhhhhhhh... What an answer... I can't believe that.... Its working now....

Comment: i think "genderLabelTapped" method is continuously execute in your code.

Comment: @V.J. : naah... check anhtu comment... that make it worked

Comment: @anhtu : Can u post this as an answer with explanation? I will accept it...

Comment: @FahimParkar simple happiness. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `setFrame` of `UIPickerView` it will call `-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view`.

In this case, to stop the loop, remove:

```
if (screenHeight==568) {
    [pickerView setFrame: CGRectMake(10, 332, 300, 216)];
} else {
    [pickerView setFrame: CGRectMake(10, 244, 300, 216)];
}
```

***P/s: If you want to change anything of an object in its delegate/callback methods, do carefully.***

Comment: between this happened with you before? bcz pointing something like this is no way easy... actually i m handling this project where someone else worked before 3 years... :(

Comment: @FahimParkar, No, I haven't dealt with this problem before. I just guess. So I didn't post the answer first.